# Wireless connection problems only on gnomebuntu

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-gnome

I'm currently using gnomebuntu 13.10 and cannot seem to connect to my high schools network. It is a WPA-EAP network usig PEAP and MD5. I've tried everything I could thing of. I did not have this problem on the unity based ubuntu.

- WPA_SUPPLICANT
- disableing and renabling the driver using modprobe
- usb wifi (stupid idea had no idea why i thought this would work)

please help me diagnose and fix this problem.

---

Kernel: 3.13

ubuntu variant: Gnome

Ubuntu version: 13.10

Wifi module: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem, it turns out that my phone uses MD5 to connect whereas my laptop uses mchapv2 to connect. FML! switches to mchapv2 fixed the problem.